# Decision Tree Gini Impurity Basic Math Q

Tags: math, machine-learning, probability, decision-tree

Say you have 3 classes of balls: red, green blue.

The odds of any colored ball appearing are red = 4/10, blue = 3/10, green = 3/10

Misclassifying red is calculated as 4/10*(3/10 + 3/10) or the odds of picking "True Class" * "Wrong Class".

Why do you multiply, instead of say add, to find the odds of picking the wrong red ball? I know the Gini Impurity equation generalizes this basic idea for all C classes with N points and Ni data points of each class. I think I forgot my basic probability intuition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability that a ball is `red` is 0.4. You can only make a mistake about a red ball if the ball is, in fact, red.

Assuming that the guess is based precisely on the probability distribution of the balls [Note 1], then a guess of blue has probability 0.3 and equally a guess of green has probability 0.3. If the ball really is red, these are the incorrect guesses, since the only other possible guess is correct.

If two events are independent, the probability that both of them occur (P **and** Q) is the product of their probabilities. If two events are mutually exclusive, then the probability that one of them occurs (P **or** Q) is the sum of their probabilities.

So the probability that a ball is red **and** is misclassified (as blue **or** green) is 0.4 * (0.3 + 0.3).

To that, we'd have to add the probability of a blue ball being misclassified as red or green (0.3 * (0.4 + 0.3)) and the probability of a green ball being misclassified as blue or red (0.3 * (0.3 + 0.4)) for a total of 0.66. That's extremely close to the maximum value of 2/3 (when all the probabilities are equal).

---

#### Notes:

1. Here I'm basing the answer on the [definition of Gini impurity from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity):

   > Gini impurity is a measure of how often a randomly chosen element from the set would be incorrectly labeled if it were randomly labeled according to the distribution of labels in the subset.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I wish I could upvote you more. This helped me immensely in grokking the idea.